# Setter not running when assigning to the same reference

Tags: c#, getter-setter, setter

My setter code is not running here, I think by design because I am setting the same reference.

Is there syntax I can use to ensure the setter runs?

```
var settings = new Settings();

var a = settings.ReferenceVariable;

a.Value1++;

settings.ReferenceVariable = a; // Setter is not running here, so changes to 'a' are not persisted in database

// One workaround is to set to a different value, then set back to my value.  This isn't a good solution for me
settings.ReferenceVariable = null; // Setter does run
settings.ReferenceVaraible = a; // Setter does run

public class Settings
{
    public MyClass ReferenceVariable
    {
        get => GetSettingValueFromDatabase();
        set => SetSettingValueToDatabase(value);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Thanks everyone for your help, I found the issue, I'm using Fody/PropertyChanged package, which does modify property setters, and checks for changes.  Their changes aren't visible to me while debugging, so it was confusing to track down

Comment: Can you show a full sample of your code? This looks alright, but it is missing a few implementation details. Also, did you put a breakpoint into SetSettingValueToDatabase to verify your assumpmtion?

Comment: Ok I added some more code.  Yes I set a breakpoint and see the setter is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "the setter is not running" - are you saying the `set => SetSettingValueToDatabase(value)` line is never reached, or are you infering this only by the fact that the expected side effects from `SetSettingValueToDatabase` are not observed?

Because my gut feeling would be that the setter and the function `SetSettingValueToDatabase` itself *are* actually called, but MyClass has an internal optimization to skip the actual database operation if the value "hasn't changed", implemented like so:

```
private MyClass _cachedValue;
private bool _isLoaded = false;

private MyClass GetSettingValueFromDatabase() {
  if (!_isLoaded) {
    _cachedValue = DoActuallyLoadFromDatabase()
    _isLoaded = true;
  }
  return _cachedValue;
}

private void SetSettingValueToDatabase(MyClass newValue) {
  if (!_isLoaded || _cachedValue != newValue) {
    DoActuallySaveToDatabase(newValue);
    _cachedValue = newValue;
    _isLoaded = true;
  }
}
```

The `!=` would then most likely fall back to `object.ReferenceEquals`, which would yield `true` since the *reference* of `newValue` and `_cachedValue` still match - hence no DB write or cache update, hence it *looks* as if the setter wasn't called, when *actually* just its side effect weren't triggered.

You can verify this by changing the property getter/setter to

```
get {
  var res = GetSettingValueFromDatabase();
  Debug.WriteLine($"get will return {res}");
  return res;
}
set {
  Debug.WriteLine($"set called with {value}");
  SetSettingValueToDatabase(value);
}
```

My suspicion is that the debug output will be

> get will return MyNamespace.MyClass
> set called with MyNamespace.MyClass
> set called with null
> set called with MyNamespace.MyClass

rather than

> get will return MyNamespace.MyClass
> set called with null
> set called with MyNamespace.MyClass

indicating the setter was indeed called as expected.

On a side note: a setter that triggers a database write operation is not a good design. Setters should be usually designed to be light-weight operations, not triggering a potentially locking hefty database operation. Rather use a method, that should potentially even be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what exactly you're doing here, but I think your comments are telling:

```
settings.ReferenceVariable = a; // Setter is not running here, so changes to 'a' are not persisted in database
```

but then you have:

```
settings.ReferenceVaraible = a; // Setter does run
```

Obviously the lines of code are exactly the same here, so my guess would be that you're expecting to link `a` to your Database, such that `a` would be a kind of a handle/portal to your database and you can modify `a` and get those changes telegraphed into your database.

This isn't going to work. The setter only runs when you set the value of `settings`, not when you set the value of `a`. It might be that you are updating `a` after the fact, but updating `a` doesn't force the call to `SetSettingValueToDatabase`.

How you handle this depends on how you want to restructure your code. I would wait to write `a` until you're done doing whatever operations you need to do with `a`, but you could also add a kind of a listener mechanic to `a`.

I have no idea what's in `a`, but you could do something like the following. This is a bit more code than I meant to write lol, but I'll put some closing comments after the code block.

```
public interface IChanged
{
    void Subscribe(System.EventHandler subscriber);
    void Unsubscribe(System.EventHandler subscriber);
}
public class MyClass : IChanged
{
    private System.EventHandler subscribers;
    private int myInt;
    public int MyInt
    {
        get => myInt;
        set
        {
            myInt = value;
            subscribers?.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    }

    private string myString;
    public string MyString
    {
        get => myString;
        set
        {
            myString = value;
            subscribers?.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    }

    public void Subscribe(System.EventHandler subscriber)
    {
        subscribers += subscriber;
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(System.EventHandler subscriber)
    {
        subscribers -= subscriber;
    }
}

public class Settings
{
    private MyClass myClass;
    public MyClass ReferenceVariable
    {
        get => GetSettingValueFromDatabase();
        set
        {
            if (myClass != null)
            {
                if (myClass != value)
                {
                    myClass.Unsubscribe(OnReferenceVariableChanged);
                }
            }
            myClass = value;
            SetSettingValueToDatabase(value);
            value.Subscribe(OnReferenceVariableChanged);
        }
    }

    private void OnReferenceVariableChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        SetSettingValueToDatabase(ReferenceVariable);
    }

    private MyClass GetSettingValueFromDatabase()
    {
        // You would get this from a Database
        return new MyClass();
    }

    private void SetSettingValueToDatabase(MyClass myClass)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Here there's an `IChanged` interface that sets up a mechanism to subscribe to changes. You don't need any information here, you just need a heads up that `a` changed. You can slap the `IChanged` interface on whatever you want and use it for a variety of classes.

The trick then is to add the `subscribers?.Invoke(this, null);` line to each property in `MyClass`. If you don't use properties then you don't have a way to add this line and thus you won't get notifications if/when the fields are changed.

Then, in `Settings`, you keep track of a `private MyClass myClass` to know when you're getting a new instance of `MyClass`, so you can unsubscribe from the old one. Fire off your `SetSettings` methods, and then `Settings` adds itself as a subscriber to the `MyClass`'s property changes.

Now, anytime a property changes, the `MyClass` class alerts all its subscribers, and the `Settings` subscriber in particular can use that as a trigger to re/write the settings to the database.

There's nothing special there in the `Settings` getter, so you might want to consider unsubscribing `myClass` there, setting it to whatever you pulled from the database, and hooking up the subscriber to that new instance, but I don't know anything about your code so I don't want to push that as "the" answer.